# Why do we say "octadiene" and at the same time name another compound "octanediol"?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Why do we say "octadiene" and at the same time name another compound "octa**ne**diol"? We also say for instance "penta**ne**dione", but on the other hand we say "butadiyne". I don't see any logical pattern for when to include the infix -**ne**- and when to exclude it.

Comment: There's nothing "irregular" in here. You got your "ne" in butadiyne just right.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In octadiene, the double bonds are an integral part of the parent chain. So if you named it 'octanediene', it would seem to exclude the double bonds from the parent chain and making the parent chain completely saturated. So to make the double bonds inclusive, it is termed as 'octadiene'.
But in case of octanediol, the hydroxy group is not a part of the parent chain, being a functional group. So it is named 'octanediol'.

Comment: If that's the case, could one not say that all compounds beginning with "metan-", "etan-", "propan-" etc. are saturated compounds? But that does not hold true if we consider propanone.

Comment: Wherever is '-ane', it means the compound is saturated. If there was unsaturation, we would have included that in parent chain according to IUPAC rules and '-ene' would have appeared. As with propanone, it has only 3 C atoms and at the other end of double bond there is O. So there can't be 'propenone' or 'propynone'.

Comment: Nomenclature follows strict rules. The argument you present here might be a well enough for of thumb, but as a real answer to the question it doesn't hold up. I'm sure there are sources, which can be quoted to support this claim. This should probably include the current edition of the Blue Book.